# how to apply css class on Button element inside the DropdownButton react-bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-bootstrap, dropdownbutton

I am using Dropdown button from react-bootstrap. I want to apply class on button element inside DropdownButton. It is applying to outer div if I pass className to DropdownButton. Instead it should get applied to button element. Below is the code I am using

```
**<DropdownButton
  className="btn-group"
  title="Assign"
  noCaret
  id="Assign"
  show={this.state.popupApplyVisible}
  onToggle={() =>
    this.setState({
      popupApplyVisible: !this.state.popupApplyVisible,
    })
  }
>**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (**bsStyle="btn-group"**) instead of (**className="btn-group"**). I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to make a dropdown `xs` size (bootstrap 4 class `btn-xs`), since the options for the `size` prop were reduced to `sm` and `lg`.

It is possible to pass custom css classes to the `DropdownButton` component using the `variant` prop. Example on a "filter by" dropdown:

```
<DropdownButton
  variant="outline-dark btn-xs"
  id="filter-button"
  menuAlign="left"
  title={intl.formatMessage({ id: `nav.${filterBy}` })}
>
  <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleChangeOrderBy('upcoming')}>
    {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.upcoming' })}
  </Dropdown.Item>
  <Dropdown.Item onClick={() => handleChangeOrderBy('past')}>
    {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.past' })}
  </Dropdown.Item>
</DropdownButton>
```